# strengths of the 3D printed part

Tags: material-science, chemical-compounds

If the material is manufactured by 3D printing (laser sintering) then what will be change in its mechanical properties than the properties by conventional one? What would be appropriate failure criteria for it?

Comment: You're not really asking a well defined question. What is "conventional" fabrication supposed to mean? There are all sorts of "conventional" ways of fabricating metal parts, including forging, casting, and mechanical machining. In addition, there are all sorts of different engineering metals and alloys, and they have different characteristics when subjected to forging, casting, mechanical machining, and (laser) powder sintering.

Comment: This is  a good question but extremely broad. It's also more of an an engineering question. But there will be definitely different crystal structure in a part that has been fused locally as in this technology as opposed to one machined from a blank / casting in a large mold.